# Find strings matching any of a large set of strings

Tags: search, command-line, grep

I have two files. One contains a list of 900 filenames. The other file contains a list of command directives, a subset of which reference the files provided in the first list. There are about 11,000 directives.

I want to extract the 900 directives that correspond to the 900 filenames in the first file.

I would like a command line solution for doing this, and if nothing else comes up I will resort to figuring out the chain of loop, grep, appending, piping, etc that is needed to do this.

But I'm hoping for a known working solution to reduce the time and errors it'll take me to work it out.

Comment: `The other file contains a list of command directives` Just to clarify... Are these bash scripts? Batch scripts? Or just a list of program names, you know the value of PATH, and you'd want to test to see if any of the program names mentioned in the `command directive` file has its (absolute) path given in the other file?

Comment: The command directives were directives to a tool we use. I needed to extract the subset that referenced the filenames that were in my list. Turned out it wasn't so hard after all :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that was easier than I thought:

```
cat file1 | xargs -l1 -I{} grep {} file2
```

Then just redirect the output to where I need it.

Maybe not the most efficient thing in the world, but it works fast enough for what I need.